# $\text{supp }u =\{0\}$ implies $u=c\delta_0$ in distributional sense?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Given $\text{supp } (u) =\{0\}$ where $u\in D(X)^\prime$ is a distribution and $X\subset \mathbb{R}$. Does this already imply that $u=c \delta_0$? for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example $\operatorname{supp} \delta'$ Is also $\{0\}$. More generally, linear combinations of derivatives of $\delta$ are supported by a single point.

Comment: Is this correct? Suppose $\text{supp }\delta^\prime=\{0\}$. By definition, this means that $\delta^\prime(\phi) =0$ for all testfunctions $\phi$ with $\text{supp }\phi \cap \{0\} = \emptyset$. But for example take $\phi\in D(\mathbb{R})$ which looks in a neighbourhood of 0 like $x\mapsto x$. Then $\text{supp }\phi \cap \{0\} = \emptyset$ but $\delta^\prime (\phi) = 1$.

Comment: @Peter if $\phi(x)=x$ is a nbh of $0$, then $\operatorname{supp} \phi$ contains $0$. (Recall that the support is a *closed* set.)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the single-element-Supplement (here: 0) you have simply $u=c (rect(x))$ where $rect(x)$ is the rectangle function which is 1 in $[- \epsilon, \epsilon]$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and Zero elsewhere. To match this with Distribution properties, you have to require normalizing; to obtain a normalized Distribution you have to choose $rect(x) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2 \epsilon}rect(x)=\delta(x)$. Therefore, a single-element-Supplement would imply $u=c \delta_0$.